# Return value for a int type return statement when there is no return statement present

Tags: c, function, return

What is the return value for an int type return statement when there is no return statement present

Why?

```
int func()
{
 printf("Hello");
}

int func1()
{

}

void main()
{
 int s,p;

 s=func();
 p=func1();
 printf("%d %d", s, p);
}
```

Comment: Title should be brief, question should be in the question section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say in a comment:

> in case of func() I am getting a return value of 5

What appears to have happened, in practice, on your machine, this time, is that the return value of `printf` (which is 5, the number of characters printed) came back to `func` in a register. `func` has not modified that register prior to its own return, and so `main` sees what appears to be the return value of `func` when it checks that same register.

You could confirm or refute this by looking at the disassembled executable code for `func`.

If this really is what has happened then it is a detail of the calling convention in use, and happenstance that `func` doesn't use the register after calling `printf`. As Kirilenko says the behavior is formally undefined, and you are not entitled to rely on it.

Comment: Then when I include a return statement in the function it behaves in a different manner, returning the value mentioned in the return statement and not that of the value returned by **printf** Why such a differnce?

Answer (score 6):

In C (that's how the question is tagged), the return value of both `func` and `func1` is undefined.

> #### C11 (n1570), § 6.9.1 Function definitions
>
> If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

Moreover, in an hosted environment, `main` return type should be `int`, not `void`. By the way, there is an exception: in C99 and C11, if the `}` that terminates `main` (*) is reached , the value returned to the environment is 0.

(*) If its return type is compatible with `int`.

Comment: But in case of func() I am getting a return value of 5

Comment: @Supmaj Read about **undefined behavior**.