# Mistakes in algorithm of finding the digital root of a number?

Tags: c, function, loops

I have a task of finding a digital root of an input number. I have written a program as followed:

```
int digital_root(int n) {
  int sum=0;
  int current=0;
  while(n/10!=0)
  {   
    sum = sum + (n%10);
    n = n/10; 
  }
  current=sum;
  if(sum > 9) digital_root(current);
  else 
  return sum;
}
```

However I am not able to get an expected result when I try to test cases. For example, I checked with the number 16, it was expected to get 7 but I got 6 instead. I do not know where I get wrong

Comment: `return digital_root(current)`

Comment: `while(n/10!=0)` --> `while(n!=0)` and `if(sum > 9) digital_root(current);` --> `if(sum > 9) return digital_root(current);`

Comment: Please turn the shown code into a full [mre].

Comment: @kaylum What keeps you from making an answer?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala What keeps you from making an answer?

Comment: @Yunnosch bc it is still a typo and might not fix it.

Comment: Not sure about a typo, but waiting for a MRE is wise of course.

Comment: Your compiler should be telling you about the mistake in not always returning a value from the function.  It won't tell you about the erroneous test in the while loop.  Nor is it likely to say that you don't need `current` — you can use `sum` alone.

Comment: You are asking your homework questions *always*.

Comment: @Yunnosch I admit I'm a bit lazy and don't want to take the time to ensure my answer covers all the cases.

Comment: @snr Asking homework questions is not wrong in itself, if the questions contain sufficient demonstration of own effort. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions If you find questions which seem like blind homework dumps ( which I think this is not really) then flag as "needs focus" and explain. Ideally referring to the compromise in the link I provided.

Answer (score -2):

substitude   `while(n!=0)`   for  `while(n/10!=0)`
and add  `return` between `if(sum > 9)`   and `digital_root(current);`

You can also delete the "current ",it does't work.Just use the "sum" will be better.

Even you can try the  “九余数定理” .

Comment: "Don't need to change the  if(sum > 9) digital_root(current);". Why not? It's clearly wrong. Not returning a value in a function that is declared to do so is undefined behaviour. Just because it appears to work in the very limited testing you have done does not mean it will always work (that is one of the characteristics of undefined behaviour).

Comment: @kaylum Probably tested and found that it happens to work, as is often the case with calculating something but forgetting to cleanly return it. "happens to work" in professional context of course means "will fail at the worst moment".

Comment: only_tao Please [edit] to add helpful or even necessary information, instead of hiding it down here in the comments.

Comment: But can you give a example when it will fail ?

Comment: According to what your said ,why not think about  if the number  is very big ,it will overflow the "int "?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15527904/7733418 and if you are not yet scared of "Undefined Behaviour", then you need more experience.

Comment: I admit I'm inexpercienced.After reading that ,I know a lot.    Thank all of you.